# button for installing pwa on next page is dissapearing

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps

does someone has worked with progressive web app with react where i added a button on click to install the app. I need a help. it is installable and working perfect the only issue is when i switch from main page to other page icon button is gone and it appears again if i refresh the page so the state is allways true to be shown,but i guess the problem is with rerouting. Any idea would be helpfull.

Have crete manifest.json file and serviceWorker, inside my index.js is

button in search bar is accessible as well

Answer (score 0):

To display the button you probably check that you have captured the [`beforeInstallPrompt`](https://web.dev/learn/pwa/installation-prompt/#the-beforeinstallprompt-event).

When you navigate to a secondary page is that variable lost? That would cause the button to disappear.